# How to increase font size or change font style of description in togglebutton widget

Tags: python, ipywidgets

```py
widgets.ToggleButtons(options=["No","Yes"], value="Yes",description="values?",)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [the docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Widget%20Styling.html). I'm not familiar with ipywidgets so I might be wrong, but I think you can do:

```py
widgets.ToggleButtons(options=["No","Yes"], value="Yes",description="values?", style=dict(
    font_size="18px",
    font_style='italic',
    font_weight='bold',
    font_variant="small-caps",
    text_color='red',
    text_decoration='underline'
))
```